# Issue with adding trusted mitmproxy certificate to the docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mitmproxy

I tried to run mitmproxy via docker to collect API requests we send from the app to the server. Already set up the process locally and start working on putting it into a docker container.

Firstly I tried to use a standard docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy

Run the following command:

> docker run --rm -it -p 8282:8080 -p 127.0.0.1:8182:8081
> mitmproxy/mitmproxy mitmweb --web-host 0.0.0.0 --web-port 8282

And faced the issue with mitmproxy certificate, while tryining to collect the 'https' traffic, it has not been trusted.

When I tried to write a custom image based on standard one through the docker file, I added a corresponding mitmproxy certificate to the container in there, but it doesn't help for some reasons.

**Not Truster sertificate example:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSWb6.png

**Browser view after performing some search:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9RXV.png

**Dockerfile:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5qOm.png

Comment: Mitmproxy uses the Python package certifi and ignores the system root CA certificates.

Comment: @Robert What would you suggest to me, to achieve my goal?

Comment: Mitmproxy has multiple [command-line options](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/). Which to use depends on if you want a real solution like `ssl_verify_upstream_trusted_confdir` or quick and dirty like `ssl_insecure`. Not sure how to use that in docker, I don't use docker. Mitmproxy is so simple that it doesn't make sense from my perspective to use docker, A simple Python venv is enough as "container".